# Can you please explain on how we can set ActivityId in Semantic Logging by using .Net 4.5.1

Tags: slab

Can  you please explain on how we can set ActivityId in Semantic Logging by using .Net 4.5.1?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`EventSource.SetCurrentThreadActivityId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249457(v=vs.110).aspx) to set the current thread activity ID.  If you need to link two activity IDs then use the [WriteEventWithRelatedActivityId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource.writeeventwithrelatedactivityid(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of the usual WriteEvent.

See [Activity tracing and sampling](https://slab.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ActivityTracingAndSampling) for more information.